# cakephp passing a variable to another controller

Tags: forms, session, cakephp

I am hoping to get pointed in the right direction. I want to pass a variable from one controller into another controller.

what I want to do is have a person register a business then they are taken to a form to register a user. a business is a different controller/table to a user however the user requires the id/primary key of the business as a foreign key in the user table. How would I go about changing controllers and carrying the foreign key over?

the primary key for the business table is an autogenerated/autoincremented int in the database
i am unsure on how I would approach this but have a feeling it is to do with session data?

Comment: Have you read the manual at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you pass the id in the url?. I'd do it like this:

- Display `/business/add`. This is the form used to create a "business".
- After saving the business in your controller, redirect to `/business/add_user/123` (where "123" is the id of your business). This page displays and saves the users. Since you have passed the business_id in the url you'd have to add it as a foreign key manually into the `$this->request->data` before saving the user.

Of course that inside the controller of `/business/add_user/123` you should verify a few thing: check if the business_id was passed as parameter in the url, check if the business exist, maybe check that the connected user was the one that created the businnes, etc

Hope this helps

Comment: i may not have worded this correctly but there are two controllers users and accounts(business).  When a person adds an account its accounts/add once they click submit they are redirected to users/add, to add a new users. 

would i used $this->request->data to pass the primary key from the accounts controller to the users controller?

Comment: The idea is the same.. you could also pass the variable in the url like `/users/add/123`